# Is "foo === bar" equal to "if (foo === bar) {return true}"?

Tags: javascript, syntax, operators

I know this question falls in the realm of "basics", however I'd like to understand the inner workings of the language.

My question is:
Do operators *'return'* the expression's value by default after evaluation?
'return' as in if we were to write:

```
//some operation using == < > etc...
return result;
```

Comment: Yes and no. We say `foo === bar` *evaluates* to `true` or `false`. The basic idea is that when the computer finds an expression, it is evaluated, then replaced with the final value. This means you can do `const result = foo === bar;` for instance. This might look weird at first, but right of the `=` is an expression that evaluates to true or false, which is then assigned to the const. The same thing happens when you do `const result = fn(...);`, the function is called and the function call is "replaced" with the returned value, again assigning it to the const.

Comment: In short, you can replace `if (foo === bar) return true; else return false;` with `return foo === bar;` and you can replace `if (foo == true)` with `if (foo)`, but rather than saying that an expression "returns" a value I'd say an expression evaluates to its value.

Comment: I definitely get your point, however while studying about "filter()" method, I ran into this snippet: "let someUsers = users.filter(item => item.id < 3);"
My understanding was that there needed to be a return statement, which is why I asked this question :)

Comment: I see, that's the short version of an arrow function. If the arrow function only has a single statement, you can remove the `{ }` and the `return`. Especially in callbacks to functions like filter() or sort() you often only see `x => expression`. Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax

Comment: Aha! finally makes sense! I guess I need to brush up on Arrow Functions :) 
Thanks a ton Chris, and thanks Ivan, really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a slight difference.

foo===bar does not return anything, it only calculates a boolean value.

You can combine this with a return statement, foo===bar to return true if foo == bar, and false otherwise.

if (foo === bar){return true} ONLY returns true if the two are equal, it would return nothing if foo does not equal bar.

Comment: Turns out OP is actually asking about [arrow functions with a concise body](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#basic_syntax).

Comment: Yep, next time I should include everything in the question.